# How to remove a file or folder from within the grub terminal?

Tags: grub2, rm

I'm encountering problem with my dual-boot installation.

I already experienced grub problems in the past, at that time I just deleted a folder (resulting from a faulty distrib install) in my `EFI` partition which seemed to corrupt my computer startup.

Today, things have reached a higher level. I can no longer access my Windows or Linux partition, nor can I access BIOS to boot on a Live USB. I'm left with the `grub` (v2.02) terminal.

By using the `ls` command, I found the faulty folder I would usually remove to fix the problem. Unfortunately, there is no `rm` command, it results in `` error: can't find command `rm` ``.

So, is there a way to remove a directory while being in the grub terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot remove or modify any file from within `grub`.

It is clearly stated in the [`grub` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html):

> GRUB deliberately does not implement support for writing files in
>   order to minimise the possibility of the boot loader being responsible
>   for file system corruption.

and later on

> Since GRUB intentionally contains no code for writing to file systems,
>   it can easily provide a guaranteed read-only mount mechanism.

You can still edit a `grub` menu entries, so if you messed up with directories perhaps changing path to the linux kernel (and initrd) or modifying chainloader parameter (in case of windows) will rescue the systems.

Comment: I suspected it was not possible, but wanted to be sure. Thanks!